# time series "forecast" R package from C++

Tags: c++, r, time-series

I can't find any documentation about how to use the "forecast" R package from C++. Is anything available online?

Answer (score 4):

I have not looked closely but as it depends on the CRAN packages [Rcpp](http://dirk.eddelbuettel.com/code/rcpp.html) and [RcppArmadillo](http://dirk.eddelbuettel.com/code/rcpp.armadillo.html) (which I am involved and which facilitate C++ use from R), I'd say yes.  You can probably poke around in the sources and find other entry points. It's open source, after all.

But if you asked for a well-defined pre-existing API for forecast, the answer may be no.

*Edit:* Oh, and the obvious plug for [RInside](http://dirk.eddelbuettel.com/code/rinside.html) which allows you to embed [a single instance of] R very easily inside your C++ application. It does this by wrapping the existing (but hard to use) embedding API in a much simpler to use C++ class which abstracts away all the handholding.